# c++ Allocating memory on real time without vector

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, pointers, vector

asking on stack again. I have an array wich I want to be always at the minimum size, because I have to send over the internet. The problem is, the program has no way to know what the minimum size is until the operation is finished. This leads me to having to ways: using vectors, or make an array of the maximum lenght the program could ever need, and then that it knows the minimum size, initialize a pointer with `new` and put the data there. But I can't use vectors because they require serialization to be sent, and both vector and serialization have overheads I don't want. Example:

```
unsigned short data[1270], // the maximum size the operation could take is 1270 shorts
*packet; // pointer
int counter; //this is to count how big "packet" will be
//example of operation, wich of course is different from my program
// in this case the operation takes 6 bytes
while(true) {
  for (int i; i != 6; i++) {
     counter++; 
     data[i]= 1;
  }
  packet=new unsigned short[counter];
  for (int i; i!=counter; i++) {
    packet[i]=data[i];
  }
}
```

Like you might have noticed, this code runs in cycles, so the problem might be my way to repeatedly re-initialize the same pointer.
The problem in this code is, if I do:

```
std::cout<<counter<<" "<<sizeof(packet)/sizeof(unsigned short)<<" ";
```

counter variates in size (usually from 1 to 35), but the size of packet is always 2. I also tried `delete []` before `new`, but it didn't solve the problem.

This issue could also be related to another part of the code, but here i am just asking:

**Is my way of repeatedly allocate memory right?**

Comment: If you want to record/store/etc. a size, use [`std::size_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t).

Comment: why not just use the max size data buffer and only send some of it?

Comment: well, i'd have to divide every single short i want to send into a unique packet, instead of sending them all together(it will be usually of about 7 - 17 shorts). Wouldn't this create overhead?

Comment: I mean when you use the socket send method. You don't have to specify the size of the buffer. You can specify the size of the data you want to send contained in that buffer.

Comment: So if I want to send only the first three bites, can i just set the buffer to three? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "set the buffer to three", but you should just be able to tell the send method that the size of the buffer is 3.

Comment: That's what i meant. The code would be like `send (Socket,(char*)&data, 3,0)`. Of course I would need to convert the values to Big-Endian byte order before. Thanks a lot, going to try tomorrow.

Comment: sorry, the size should be 3*sizeof(short)

Comment: `vector` is just a wrapper for `new[]`, IDK what "vectors require serialization to be sent" is supposed to mean. Vectors don't have any overheads , unless you consider storing both `size` and `capacity` to be an overhead

Comment: Massive memory leak right there. There must be a `delete` for every `new`. If you keep allocating memory and never release it, you will eventually use it all.

Comment: You can always keep track of how many packets you have with the "size" of the array by using a size variable. The size will tell you how many packets you have in your array regardless of your array length. When you want to send the packets, you only call the loop with the "size" and not the "length" of the array. So if you have an array, whose length is 50 and the current elements or packets are only 12, then your size will be 12.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I (only)sometimes don't like `std::vector<T>` initializing its element with `T{}`.  We may call it "overhead"

Comment: @nodakai don't do that then... you can construct the elements directly in the vector

Comment: @MattMcNabb We cannot do so when we construct a `std::vector` instance to use with `recv()`.  Anyways this perhaps nit-picking... The difference is almost always negligible in such a context.

Answer (score 1):

Continually add to an `std::vector` while *requesting* to the compiler that the size allocated in heap memory not exceed the amount actually needed:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::size_t const maxSize = 10;
for (std::size_t i; i != maxSize; ++i)
{
  vec.reserve(vec.size() + 1u);
  vec.push_back(1234); // whatever you're adding
}
```

I should add though that I see no good reason for doing this under normal circumstances. The performance of this "program" could be severely hampered with no obvious benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use pointers and realloc. C++ is such a powerfull language because of its pointers, you don't need to use arrays.

Take a look at the [cplusplus entry on realloc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/realloc/).

For your case you could use it like this:

```
new_packet = (unsigned short*) realloc (packet, new_size * sizeof(unsigned short));

if (new_packet!=NULL) {
   packet = new_packet;
   for(int i ; i < new_size ; i++)
       packet[i] = new_values[i];
}
else {
   if( packet != NULL )
       free (packet);
   puts ("Error (re)allocating memory");
   exit (1);
}
```

Comment: I did declare. if you look, after "[1270]" there is a comma, not a ";".

Comment: Gonna read the link tomorrow and let you know, thanks in advance.

Comment: Ah, ok, hadn't seen the comma!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see a couple problems in your logic here. Lets start with the main one: Why do you need to alloc a whole fresh array with a copy of whats in `data` just to send it over a socket? It's not like sending a letter dude, `send()` will transfer a copy of the information, not literally move it over the network. It's perfectly fine to do this:

```
send(socket, data, counter * sizeof(unsigned short), 0);
```

There. You don't need a new pointer for anything.

Also, I don't know where you got the serialization thing from. Vectors are basically arrays that resize automatically, and will also delete themselves from memory once the function is done. You could do this:

```
std::vector<unsigned short> packet;
packet.reserve(counter);
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
    packet[i] = data[i];

send(socket, &packet[0], packet.size() * sizeof(unsigned short), 0);
```

Or even shorten to:

```
std::vector<unsigned short> packet;
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < counter; ++i)
    packet.push_back(data[i]);
```

But with this option the vector will resize `counter` times, what is performance consuming. Always set its size first if you have the information available.

Comment: It will almost certainly *not* resize `counter` times. Sometimes along the lines of `log2(counter)` would be more likely.

Comment: Why that if the object `packet` don't even know the value of `counter`? Only if the compiler do some optimization.

Comment: actually, it will resize `counter` times but it won't reallocate memory that many times. So performance is not impacted linearly with the size of `counter`.